# How to add shadow to UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiview

[image: Result which i get]For `UIView` I'm giving corner radius for two sides and adding drop shadow. Now, I'm getting corner radius for two sides but not shadow.

Here is the code which I have used:

```
@IBOutlet var myView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   let shadowpath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
   myView.frame.height, height: myView.frame.height), byRoundingCorners: 
   [.topRight, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 58.0, height: 0.0))

    myView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.4)  //Here you 
    control x and y
    myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    myView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0 //Here your control your blur
    myView.layer.masksToBounds =  false
    myView.layer.shadowPath = shadowpath.cgPath
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Show the rest of that code, please. Are you also masking the layer? Where is the code that draws that rounded corner shape?

Comment: What is expected? I fail to see what's wrong.

Comment: @user28434 expected as screenshot result

Comment: Ok, then can you show what happens now? Like current state screenshot.

Comment: @user28434 yeah, sure!

Comment: @user28434 can you check results which i get in simulator

Comment: @matt i'm using byRoundingCorners in UIBezierPath

Comment: Ok, your shadow is fine. You have problem with the view/it's root layer itself. It doesn't look you properly set corner radii.

Comment: @user28434 if i remove shadow code, the corner radii of two side shows fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use a "container" view... you add a "shadow layer" as a Sublayer of the container view, and add the masked view as a Subview of the container.

Here is an example you can run in a Playground, that will give you just about what you've shown as your goal (you'll probably want to tweak the color values and shadow radius and offset):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TestViewController : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0)

        let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        myView.backgroundColor = .white

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()

        let shadowpath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:
            myView.frame.height, height: myView.frame.height), byRoundingCorners:
            [.topRight, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 58.0, height: 0.0))

        mask.path = shadowpath.cgPath
        myView.layer.mask = mask

        let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shadowLayer.frame = myView.bounds
        shadowLayer.path = shadowpath.cgPath
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        shadowLayer.masksToBounds = false
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 1.0)

        let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: myView.bounds.width, height: myView.bounds.height))
        container.backgroundColor = .clear
        container.layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer)
        container.addSubview(myView)

        view.addSubview(container)

    }

}

let vc = TestViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found answer by myself by giving  layerMaxXMinYCorner and layerMaxXMaxYCorner

```
   myView.clipsToBounds = true
    myView.layer.cornerRadius = 58
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        myView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, 
  .layerMaxXMaxYCorner ]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    let shadowpath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.myView.bounds, 
    byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 
   58.0, height: 0.0))



    myView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)  //Here you 
    control x and y
    myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    myView.layer.shadowRadius = 15 //Here your control your blur
    myView.layer.masksToBounds =  false
    myView.layer.shadowPath = shadowpath.cgPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy extension to use directly from storyboard. Swift 4+

```
@IBDesignable extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor?{
        set {
            guard let uiColor = newValue else { return }
            layer.shadowColor = uiColor.cgColor
        }
        get{
            guard let color = layer.shadowColor else { return nil }
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float{
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
        get{
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize{
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        }
        get{
            return layer.shadowOffset
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat{
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
        get{
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Swift 5+ solution:

```
let tempView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -50, width: self.view.frame.size.width/1.4, height: 300))

//below is the code you need to add, adjust Opacity as needed
        tempView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        tempView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        tempView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        tempView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5+ Solution**

```
extension UIView{
    func dropShadowWithCornerRaduis() {
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = 25
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 1
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
       
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
contentView.dropShadowWithCornerRaduis()
```